# SKView integrated into UIViewController with UITextFields lagging

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uitextfield, skscene

I am trying to use a `SKView` in my login UI for some animations. The `SKView` is added as a subview to a `LoginContainerView` as well as the view containing the UITextFields and the sign in button. All of the subviews are positioned with autolayout and the `FireScene` attached to the `SKView` has it's scaleMode set to `.resizeFill`.

The issue I'm having is very clear to observe from this clip: https://streamable.com/5it17 .

> Clip explanation: Whenever I **double tap** any of the UITextFields (to trigger the
>   UIMenuController / Paste button) the `FireScene` freezes for a brief
>   amount of time (yet it's very noticeable) and the FPS drops down to around 30 for 1-2 seconds.

The only node that the `FireScene` has added as its child node is a modified fireflies SKEmitterNode template. I'm fairly certain that this has nothing to do with the actual code (as it is very straightforward and concise) and is probably a UIKit mixed with SpriteKit bug.

Relevant code:

```
class FireScene: SKScene {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var fireSparkEmitter: SKEmitterNode? = nil

    // MARK: - Inherited
    override func didChangeSize(_ oldSize: CGSize) {
        // position the emitter to scene's center
        fireSparkEmitter?.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        if let emitter = fireSparkEmitter {
            emitter.resetSimulation()
        } else {
            guard let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "FireSparks.sks") else { return }
            addChild(emitter)
            fireSparkEmitter = emitter
        }

    }
}

class LoginContainerView: UIView {
    /// ...
    let fireBackgroundScene: FireScene = {
        let scene = FireScene(size: .zero)
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        return scene
    }()
    /// ...

    // MARK: - Inherited
    // called after view initialization
   func setupSubviews() {
        let skView = SKView(frame: .zero)
        skView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(skView)
        skView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        skView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        skView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        skView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.presentScene(fireBackgroundScene)
    }
}
```

PS: I've tried to profile the app with Time Profiler and it seems that the bottleneck is the UITextField gesture handling by UIKit itself.

Comment: What is calling setupSubviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems related to a different layout syncronization between `SKView` and the other `UIKit` objects. 
`SKView` have a property called [*isAsynchronous*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520229-isasynchronous) (**default = true**) that indicates 
 whether the content is rendered asynchronously.
You can try to set:

```
skView.isAsynchronous = false
```

to syncronize your `SKView` with the core animation updates.
This could be not enough because you'll syncronize `SKView` with the **Core Animations** of your project but there are always the **UIKit-style animations** that could be out of sync.
If this property don't solve your issue you can change also the [preferredFramesPerSecond](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1642773-preferredframespersecond) property. Remember that when you try to mix two frameworks (`sprite-kit` and `UIKit`) you will inevitably incur to unpleasant hitches.

Comment: Unforunately setting the `isAsynchronous` property to `false` didn't change anything. The fps behaviour is still the same. I'm probably going to leave the SpriteKit path and play around with `CAEmitterLayer` instead.. Thanks regardless.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good decision. `sprite-kit` don't offer helps when you work with `UIKit`, especially using `SKEmitterNode`

Comment: Another gotcha: if you want to overlay an SKView so that the (UIKit) background shows through, you need to set the SKView's backgroundColor to .clear (not nil) and you must also enable 'allowsTransparency'. Otherwise GPU usage will choke. Finally, the SKScene must also have a backgroundColor of .clear